# How to undo vestiges of themes past

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-8

hardware: Samsung Galaxy S8+ (SM-G955U)
software: Android 7.0 (Nougat)

In December, I installed Samsung's "White Winter" theme. Then I installed "For Snowy Porch" in January followed by "winter tree" in February. The problem I'm having is that there are elements of the White Winter theme that remain on the phone even after installing two other themes afterward. Here are the elements that remain and that I now wish to change to something that better matches the theme I currently have installed:

1. The left and right app shortcuts on the lock screen (the phone and camera). Note that I am not trying to change the apps that are launched by these shortcuts. I am trying to change the appearance. I want to replace the icon.
2. The background image that appears when the settings menu is pulled up. It is currently set to the background image for the White Winter theme. I would like to change it to something else.
3. Similarly to #2 , the background image that appears when I bring up the phone app (showing "recents", "contacts", or the number pad). It shows the background image for the White Winter theme, and I would like to change it.
4. Also on the phone app, when I display contacts and scroll down to contacts just after "frequently contacted", there is a section for contacts that start with symbols. The section is labeled "&". E.g., "#BAL", and "#DATA". The icons that display to the left of those contacts are from the White Winter theme. I'd like to restore them all to the way they were. I could do this one by one, but I was hoping there was a way to just replace the entire icon pack at once.

Thanks!

Comment: I've never used themes, so I don't know much about it, but can't you just uninstall the winner theme and it will automatically go away?

Comment: I don't see an option to uninstall themes.

Comment: Check in settings > themes > delete

Comment: There is no "settings > themes".  There is "Settings > Wallpapers and themes", but at that point, there is no "delete".

Comment: I don't have themes, so I can't test this but can you long press on the theme and delete?

Comment: No, nothing happens with a long press.

Comment: C'mon there most be a way to delete this thing! How do you even download them? If it's from Google play store, maybe you can search for one you have and uninstall it? I'm curious to know why they make it so hard to uninstall the thing

Comment: Not from Google play store.  It is from "Samsung Themes".  When I select it again, it only gives the option to "Reapply". ---- Is there no way to undo this piece by piece?  E.g., #2 in my original question, how to set the background image for the settings menu?

Comment: My phone doesn't have themes, so I can't test that. You can try googling it. Also you can edit your question, even a small edit, and your question will be bumped to the top, and others will have a chance to answer

Comment: Thanks, Bouchur for your time and suggestions.  I'll edit the question as you suggested.